# How to store document field in a list using Dart

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve an array field from a document and store it in a list object.

Here's what I have attempted so far:

```
   List<String> list;

Firestore.instance.collection("ingredients").document("Cutlet").get()
.then((snapshot) => list = snapshot.data["ingredients"]);

debugPrint("list is" + list.toString());
return list;
```

The debugPrint return null.

Here's the snapshot of my firestore. I am trying to retrieve the ingredients array and store it in the list.

[image]

Comment: Try to print/return the list inside then or use await

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 DocumentSnapshot doc= await Firestore.instance.collection('ingredients').document('cutlet').get();
  if(doc.exists) {
    var list = doc['ingredients'].map<dynamic>((item) {
      return item;
    }).toList();
  }
```